# Php and ajax not returning any data from database, no errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have created a search using ajax and php, however when I click the search button nothing happens. There are no errors, however when I look at the network in the console it doesn't seem to be reaching searching.php as this file doesn't show up in the network. I want to be able to put the returned data from the search into seperate divs, although at the minute it isn't returning any data at all and I have no idea why.

This is my php

```
require_once('config1.php');

$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['search']) === true && empty($_POST['search']) === false){



    $query = "SELECT a.attraction_name, a.lat, a.long, a.cost, a.image FROM zz_attractions a INNER JOIN zz_city c ON a.city_id = c.city_id WHERE c.city_name = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['search'])) . "' ";


    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($count == 0) { 
        $output = 'there was no search results';

    } else {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
            $attraction_name = $row['attraction_name'];
            $lat = $row['lat'];
            $long = $row['long'];
            $cost = $row['cost'];
            $image = "<img src='{$row['image']}' height='100' width='100'>";

            $output .= '<div>'.$attraction_name.' '.$lat.' '.$long.' '.$cost.' '.$image.'</div>';

        }
    }
}
```

This is my ajax

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var search = $('#search').val();

    if ($.trim(search) != '') { //if search is not equal to nothing - using trim allows users to type in blank space and it won't return anything 
        $.post('searching.php', {search: search}, function(data) {
            $('#return').text(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Within the html the div id is #return. If someone could help me find out why no data is returning that would be great.

Comment: Need to prevent default form submit and make sure `#submit` exists when code is run

Comment: @charlietfl The button looks like this <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" value= "search" type="required" id="submit" name="submit">Search</button> however it was all working before I started to add my database to it. Was echoing very simple function in php and they were working. Just not sure why it isn't echoing any information from my database

Comment: When you say _"no errors"_, does that mean that you've checked the servers error log?

Comment: Where do you output the `$output`?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am not sure what that is, but there are no php errors that appear on the screen and there are no javascript/html errors in the console log. Where can I check the servers error log?

Comment: You don't echo the output variable. Also since you say it does not get to the php file, verify that the path exists

Comment: @MagnusEriksson this is what I am not sure about and this is why I think my search is broken. I originally didn't use ajax and the $output was from my original code that worked. However I don't know how to output the database fields into my div with the id #return

Comment: You create a variable that contains the content you want to return from PHP. To actually return it, you need to output it. Just do `echo $output;` in the end of the file. PHP has no clue what your intentions for that variable is.

Comment: @Akintunde I tried putting echo infront of the output line at the bottom but nothing happened. How do I verify that the path exists?

Comment: I just realised that when I click search the page is refreshing too which is obviously not meant to happen because it is ajax

Comment: Exactly what I was saying in first comment. Change to `type="button"` and/or prevent default event

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have tried to debug it a little, I took out all my php and echoed 'hello' and when I clicked search 'hello' flashed up and then disappeared. There is no jquery features on this to make it do this. Do you have any idea why it won't connect to the searching.php file properly?

Comment: @charlietfl the first time I changed the button type it didn't work. I am getting one but massive list of divs now, is there any way I can separate each piece of data out? Rather than all of the data going into one div?

Comment: Lots of ways , that's a really broad question by itself